# Android emulator keyboard input from Numberpad no longer working

Tags: android, input, keyboard, emulation

The emulator used to accept numerical input from my number-pad with num lock on, now, however, it acts as if num lock is off.  For example, if I type "7" on my number-pad, it responds as if "Home" has been pressed.

The numerical keys along the top are still fine, and it makes no difference if I toggle num lock.

Emulator version output:

```
Android emulator version 29.0.9.0 (build_id 5537588) (CL:N/A)
Copyright (C) 2006-2017 The Android Open Source Project and many others.
This program is a derivative of the QEMU CPU emulator (www.qemu.org).

  This software is licensed under the terms of the GNU General Public
  License version 2, as published by the Free Software Foundation, and
  may be copied, distributed, and modified under those terms.

  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
  GNU General Public License for more details.
```

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04

Does anyone know what I've changed or is this a bug?

Comment: I am facing this same issue. Also I can not input text using the alphanumeric keyboard. And the same as you, everything was working before.
Have you fixed this?

Comment: did you find what's causing that?

Comment: Bug reported: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/135141621

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug in the Android Emulator.

See:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/135141621

Comment: And now this has been fixed and I can acknowledge that the latest updated to Emulator today fixes it. Please mark this as answer.

Comment: It looks like this has introduced a new bug, as my keyboard entry now seems to be entering special characters.

Comment: Yes but I was able to turn it off somehow but now the keyboard entered in upper case. Anyway, you can just mark this as answer as it is the correct answer, it's a bug in Emulator.

Comment: Looks like the "Alt" key toggles the special character mode.

Comment: thanks. I probably did Alt + Tab when it started happening. :)